# How can I make an app on android start automatically, when an email arrives?

Tags: android, email

I would like my Android application to react to an incoming email from specific address.
I've heard that you can do it with incoming SMS, but emails are cheaper. Unfortunately, I am not an expert on Android's "intents", so would be really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no documented broadcast `Intent`s for the receipt of emails. As such, what you are trying to do is not possible without either writing your own email client, or contributing to another one (e.g., K9).